# Angular input directive not working as expected in IE8 and IE9

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I am using the input directive in AngularJS and wish to set a min value on it. My understanding is that if a value lower than the min is entered, an error is shown on the ngModelController.

I've created [this plunker](http://run.plnkr.co/plunks/Y3eyguZpLME5oNZA80Xu/) with two tests which looks as follows:

```
describe("myProblem", function () {
    var ctrl;

    beforeEach(inject(function ($compile, $rootScope) {
        var scope = $rootScope.$new();
        scope.qty = 100;
        var el = angular.element('<input ng-model="qty" type="number" min="0" step="1" placeholder="0" />');
        $compile(el)(scope);
        scope.$digest();
        ctrl = el.controller("ngModel");
    }));

    it("should have a validation error when the entered value is below the min", function() {
        expect(ctrl.$valid).toBe(true);
        ctrl.$setViewValue("-1");
        expect(ctrl.$valid).toBe(false);
    });

    it("should have an $error with key of min when entered value is below min", function() {
        expect(ctrl.$error.min).toBe(false);
        ctrl.$setViewValue("-1");
        expect(ctrl.$error.min).toBe(true);
    });
});
```

The tests pass in Chrome and IE10+, but not in IE8 and IE9 (which I have to support).

Kudos to anyone who can tell me why?

Comment: Just FYI that variable "scope" in the `beforeEach()` call should (I think) be explicitly declared with `var`.

Comment: Good spot! My copy and paste skills are diminishing. Changed here and in plunk.

Comment: Input of type number is not supported by IE 8 and IE 9. Here is the reference http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-number

Comment: But the Angular docs say that it polyfills the behaviour for older browsers https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/input.

Comment: Why would you want to test something, that is not supported in real life? Even if the behavior is emulated by the test framework.

Comment: I'm not sure you understand the question I have asked. The test framework isn't emulating anything. <input> is an Angular directive that gives some enhanced form behaviour in older browsers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have fixed it and thought I'd post here in case it's useful to anyone else.

I needed to prefix the attributes that IE8 & 9 doesn't know about with data- to ensure older IE versions don't remove them from the DOM.

I've updated the plunk, but essentially I changed one line above to look like the one below:

```
var el = angular.element('<input ng-model="qty" data-type="number" data-min="0" step="1" placeholder="0" />');
```

Note the **data-** prefix to two of the attibutes in the html string.